# Error: It looks like you called `mount()` without a global document being loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

me sale este error al ejecutar mis pruebas.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { chai,  assert } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import { Factory } from 'meteor/dburles:factory';
import faker from 'faker';
import StubCollections from 'meteor/hwillson:stub-collections';


import {Button, FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl, HelpBlock, 
        ButtonToolbar, Checkbox, Radio, Glyphicon} from 'react-bootstrap';

import MainApp  from '/imports/ui/MainApp.jsx';
import {Companies} from '/imports/api/companies.js';

import {
  insert,
} from '/imports/api/companies.js';




describe('Server', () => {


    Factory.define('user', Companies, {
      firstName: () => 'Daniel',
      lastName: () => 'Peña',
      orgType: () => 'non-profit',
    });

    if (Meteor.isServer) 

        it('Se insertan los datos', () => {

            const users = Factory.create('user');
            StubCollections.stub(Companies);
            Companies.insert({ users });
            assert.equal(Companies.find().count(), 1);
            StubCollections.restore();
        });

        it('No se insertan los datos al no seleccionar el TOS', () => {
            const main = mount(<MainApp/>);

            const users = Factory.create('user');
            StubCollections.stub(Companies);

            main.find('div.checkbox').simulate('change', {
              target: { checked: false }
            });

            Companies.insert({ users });
            assert.equal(Companies.find().count(), 0);
            StubCollections.restore();
        });

    return;


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error puede ocurrir cuando estás en un entorno sin navegador. Según la [documentación de enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html) (traducción mía):

> Como la API de enzyme `mount` requiere un DOM, JSDOM es necesario para poder usar `mount` si no estás aún en un entorno de navegador (por ejemplo, un entorno Node).

En el github de airbnb hay un par de [bugs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/341) [similares](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/75) que reciben el mismo mensaje de error que indicas. En ambos casos lo solucionaron importando JSDOM y creando un "DOM vacío". El código es algo como esto (copiado del primer enlace):

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom'
const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')
global.document = doc
global.window = doc.defaultView
```